Is a WMS raster usable in QField?
Is a WMS raster usable in QField? The layer loads in QField but is not queryable. In QGIS all works OK and is queryable.

I dont think it is possible to query / identify a WMS layer.
See:
Feature suggestion: Identify WMS layers
